# python setup.py install error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fmin referenced in function fatal error LNK1120:

Tags: python

I am new to python. 
I am trying to install a module in python by visual studio code in terminal and I have provided all the requirements but it gives me an error:

> "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fmin referenced in function
>   __pyx_pf_9traj_dist_6cydist_18basic_geographical_10c_point_to_path build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\traj_dist\cydist\basic_geographical.pyd :
>   fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals error: command
>   'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe' failed with exit status
>   1120"

I download it from https://github.com/bguillouet/traj-dist

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to do the same thing, I encountered the same problem. I also wanted to install the `tra_dist` module. According to the error message, I also installed Microsoft Visual C Compiler for Python 2.7, but I still got an error. I guess it is a problem with the python version and the C compilation environment, so I tried the following:

1. python2.7 32bit installation error: `"... link.exe 'failed with exit status 1120"`
2. python2.7 64bit installation error: `".... Visual C for Python \ 9.0 \ VC \ Bin \ cl.exe" 'failed with exit status 2"`
3. python3.6.1 32bit installation prompts the need to install VC ++ compilation environment, so I installed Visual Studio 2017 C desktop and then used pycharm to install “trajectory-distance”. **It worked**

The third method is feasible. Later, after I installed Visual Studio 2017, I tried to install the "trajectory-distance" module under python2.7 and the same error occurred. The specific reason is unknown.

Comment: It's a little unclear, but I think you are suggesting to use Python 3.6.1. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I used python3.6.1(32bit), and installed Visual Studio 2017 C ++ desktop, and then searched for "trajectory-distance" module through pycharm, installation was successful